# Set up the depth of the subsection enumeration also in the Table of Contents

Tags: sectioning, section-titles

In order to set the level until which (sub)sections are numbered, a user can set up the counter `secnumdepth`.

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{whatever}
```

The trick works completely fine. However, if you try to increase the depth of the enumeration (for example up to `4`), the change is not reflected in the **Table of Contents** at the beginning of the document.
Specifically, it continues to show just the old depth of Chapter-Section-Subsection. No `subsubsections` appear
How to add the numeration automatically in the **Table of Contents**?

Comment: Hope `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}` will helps you

Comment: your comment and the answer to the other question suggested solves my problem